# Firebase returning null but data exists

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've spent hours looking for the reason why my code isn't retrieving the filed "firstName" from this structure X :/

[image: Firebase structure]

When I'm in debug I can see that Firebase retrieves all the other fields at the same level as "firstName" but this last one is always null, even though it has valid data in it.

[image: Debugged object]

This is the line where I'm creating FirestoreRecyclerOptions:

```
FirestoreRecyclerOptions<X> optionsFirestore = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<X>().setQuery(queryFirestore, X.class).build();
```

I'm a beginner in Android and I'll appreciate any help / explanation.

Thank you in advance for your help !

**EDIT:**

Here's my queryFirestore:

```
queryFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("idea").whereEqualTo("uid", currentUser.getUid());
```

And the X class is a POJO containing the data structure:

```
public class X {

public String uid;
public String avatar;
public String firstName;
public String lastName;
public Integer age;
public String title;
public String category;
public String location;
public String comment;

public X() {
}

public X(String uid, String avatar, String firstName, String lastName, Integer age, String title, String category, String location, String comment) {
    this.uid = uid;
    this.avatar = avatar;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    this.title = title;
    this.category = category;
    this.location = location;
    this.comment = comment;
}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}

public String getAvatar() {
    return avatar;
}

public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
    this.avatar = avatar;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public Integer getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(Integer age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public String getComment() {
    return comment;
}

public void setComment(String comment) {
    this.comment = comment;
}
}
```

Comment: It is hard to grasp check if your reference is correct.

Comment: There is a lot of missing information here.  Please edit the question to show how you build `queryFirestore`, and the code of the `X` class.

Comment: I have edited my question by adding the code of the `X` class and the line where I build my Firestore query. Please let me know if you need other information that would help understanding the issue.

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท yes the 2 fields `age` and `lastName` are both null, and that is showed correclty as null in the debug. My problem is with the field `firstName` that contains data that is not retrieved :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in `setFirstName()`:

```
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    firstName = firstName;
}
```

Try changing it to:

```
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
```

That's why ...

Comment: That was it !! I fixed and it's working now ! But how does an error in the setter creates a malfunctioning in the getter ? O_o
Thank you so much !

Comment: If it was **auto generated** by AS yes, weird. Nice catch BTW right? :) Happy coding pal.

Comment: I was looking everywhere but my eyes didn't pay much attention at that setter .. You did brilliant here :)) Thanks again !

Comment: Yeah it was pretty weird at first because codes were exactly like the same and needed just some attention. Glad to help :) YW.